# Is it possible to increment a database value without making a query to the database?

Tags: mysql, database

I am using a `mysql` database and have table called `timeslots` the columns for `timeslot` are `time_slot_id`, `name`, `openings`, and `appointments`. What I want to do is **update** the value of `appointments` by 1 when I add an appointment to another table.

One way to do this, would be to make a query to the database and get the value of `appointments` and then add one to it. However, would rather just update the table without having to make a request to the database to get this information.

I'm wondering if this is possible; if so, how?

Comment: `UPDATE timeslots SET appointments = appointments + 1 WHERE ...`

Comment: `... client='$client_id'`

Comment: You could look into triggers, although that is kind of like swatting a fly with a car, for something so minor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE timeslot
SET appointments = appointments + 1
WHERE time_slot_id = ?;

INSERT INTO other_table(..., time_slot_id) VALUES (..., ?);

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! That worked like a charm! I'll accept as soon as I can. Thank you again. :)

Comment: @zeflex I assumed he would do the insert in another statement, added now to answer to make it clear.

Comment: Your first answer was exactly what I needed. Thank you regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Blaine, trigger is the answer, just create something like that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_timeslots
AFTER INSERT ON my_table_appointments
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE timeslots 
  SET appointments = appointments + 1 
  WHERE timeslots.time_slot_id = NEW.time_slot_id
END;
```

I hope it helps =)